# How to customize x axis value in horizontal mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

It may be dumb question am using horizontal mpandroid barchart am having numbers in x axis like 6,000,000 so x axis getting collapsed so what is need to do is convert the number into indian rupees like 6 cr how can i do this so far what i have tried is:

This is where am setting value for horizontal barchart:

```
  ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        Format format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
      //  System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("100000000")));



        for(int i=0;i<listobj.size();i++){
          String s=  format.format(listobj.get(i).getData());
        //    Log.e("ss", s);
//            Integer numberformat=Integer.parseInt(s);
            entries.add(new BarEntry(listobj.get(i).getData(),i));
            labels.add(listobj.get(i).getLabel());
        }
        XAxis axis=barChart.getXAxis();
        BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
        //dataset.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
        BarData datas = new BarData(labels, dataset);
      ///  datas.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
        barChart.setData(datas);
        barChart.setDescription("Description");
        barChart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

This is value Formatter:

```
/**
 * Created by 4264 on 30-05-2016.
 */

import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
 * Predefined value-formatter that formats large numbers in a pretty way.
 * Outputs: 856 = 856; 1000 = 1k; 5821 = 5.8k; 10500 = 10k; 101800 = 102k;
 * 2000000 = 2m; 7800000 = 7.8m; 92150000 = 92m; 123200000 = 123m; 9999999 =
 * 10m; 1000000000 = 1b; Special thanks to Roman Gromov
 * (https://github.com/romangromov) for this piece of code.
 *
 * @author Philipp Jahoda
 * @author Oleksandr Tyshkovets <olexandr.tyshkovets@gmail.com>
 */
class LargeValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private static String[] SUFFIX = new String[]{
            "", "k", "m", "b", "t"
    };
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 4;
    private DecimalFormat mFormat;
    private String mText = "";

    public LargeValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###E0");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a formatter that appends a specified text to the result string
     *
     * @param appendix a text that will be appended
     */
    public LargeValueFormatter(String appendix) {
        this();
        mText = appendix;
    }

    // ValueFormatter
   @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return makePretty(value) + mText;
    }


    // YAxisValueFormatter


    /**
     * Set an appendix text to be added at the end of the formatted value.
     *
     * @param appendix
     */
    public void setAppendix(String appendix) {
        this.mText = appendix;
    }

    /**
     * Set custom suffix to be appended after the values.
     * Default suffix: ["", "k", "m", "b", "t"]
     *
     * @param suff new suffix
     */
    public void setSuffix(String[] suff) {
        if (suff.length == 5) {
            SUFFIX = suff;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Formats each number properly. Special thanks to Roman Gromov
     * (https://github.com/romangromov) for this piece of code.
     */
    private String makePretty(double number) {

        String r = mFormat.format(number);

        r = r.replaceAll("E[0-9]", SUFFIX[Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 1)) / 3]);

        while (r.length() > MAX_LENGTH || r.matches("[0-9]+\\.[a-z]")) {
            r = r.substring(0, r.length() - 2) + r.substring(r.length() - 1);
        }

        return r;
    }

    }
```

I don't know how to customize the x axis value how can i do this can anyone help me out thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options that you can try to solve your issue
1) While inserting the value you can divide the value by 1000,000 and change your label to 6Cr . I have a chart that has values from 0 to 30 and one value is 4000. While storing the value in database I divide it by 100 and while displaying I change the label to show the correct value
Sample SQL insert value :

```
 Float.valueOf(LEUCO_COUNT.getText().toString()) / 1000,
```

2) Option 2 is to divide the value by 1000,000 before displaying it and also modify your babel to show Cr. You can go throught he API to find how to set a custom label

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace existing function with below function.It working for me.

private String makePretty(double number) {

```
    double Cr = 10000000;
    double Lac = 100000;

    String result = mFormat.format(number);
    try {
        double LAmt = Double.parseDouble(result);
        String Append = "";
        if (LAmt > Cr) {//1Crore
            LAmt /= Cr;
            Append = "Cr";
        } else {
            LAmt /= Lac;
            Append = "L";
        }
        result = CommonUtils.GetFormattedString("" + LAmt) + Append;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.d("", "");
    }
    return result;
}
```